# Jquery remove parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text box that needs to be removed which works when there is no span wrapped around it so:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" 
value="Text + FieldCount +'" class="form-control"/>
<button class="removeclass">&times;</button></div>');
x++;
```

I am using bootstrap so I want to be able to wrap it around a span so the button and text field is attached to each other so when I wrap it around a span and button like this:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" 
value="Text '+ FieldCount +'" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
<a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></button></span></div>');
x++;
```

It doesn't remove the parent, I know why it doesn't work because the below is looking for a div as a parent to remove.

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){
    if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
    }
```

I'm not too good with jquery so I think I'm missing how to remove the div, span and button, how can I remove the div, span and button?

I've tried to add span and div inside the remove function but only one or the other is being removed something like this:

```
$(this).parent('div','span').remove();
            x--;
```

and

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('span').parent('button').remove();
```

Comment: You can't have line breaks in Javascript strings.

Comment: Just change it to `$(this).closest('div').remove();`

Comment: The DIV isn't the parent any more, it's the great-grandparent. Use `.closest()`.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. There's no line breaks in the original btw.

Comment: If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @adeneo this only works on chrome, doesn't work on ff and ie. Any ideas?